# Build an alert in a separate class to request for GPS enabling

Tags: android, gps, alert, android-alertdialog

I am trying to build an alert to tell the user that his GPS is disabled, and when pressing OK to be taken to the Settings to enable it. It is a class outside of MainActivity.

The problem is that I cannot start the activity based on Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS). I get:

```
The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}
```

I tried extending `AlertDialogManager extends Activity`, but then I get a NullPointerException error.

```
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3464)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3425)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at com.example.places.AlertDialogManager$1.onClick(AlertDialogManager.java:42)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:185)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
07-09 15:46:17.922: E/AndroidRuntime(17275):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the source code:

```
public class AlertDialogManager {
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);

        if (status != null)
            builder.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.ic_launcher : R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 5);                          
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 5 && resultCode == 0) {
            String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            if (provider != null) {
                switch (provider.length()) {
                case 0:
                    // GPS still not enabled..
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is now enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // the user did not enable his GPS
        }
    }
}
```

If I build this alert in MainActivity it works ok, but I want it separate. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register a BroadcastReceiver that listens to [PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION) intent that is sent by the system when location provider state is changed. Receiver should be declared in your *Manifest.xml* file. When you receive the aforementioned intent try to check out if GPS provider state has changed and display your dialog accordingly.

Try following code:
`// declaring local Context reference`
`final Context context = context.getApplicationContext();`
`// use this reference to start prefered Activity`
`context.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings. ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));`

Comment: My problem is not checking if the user enabled it or not. I just want that when you press OK in the alert, to be taken to the Location services settings to enable GPS. I would be ok even with startActivity() instead of startActivityForResult(), if it worked

Comment: Try following code:
context.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings. ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS ));

Comment: The first parameter from showAlertDialog() method you declared in AlertDialogManager class.

Comment: then I get: Cannot refer to a non-final variable context inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: Did you try to make _context_ parameter final?

Comment: I did and it's working now. But is this a valid solution? I've never seen something like this, a context defined as static

Comment: Why _static_? It should be _final_, I supposed.

Comment: I meant final, sorry. Same questions for final :)

Comment: You may always create a local final variable and use it instead of non-final parameter, for example:
`final Context ctx  = context.getApplicationContext();`